# Comparative statements in styled components

Tags: css, styled-components

Its a general query.
In normal CSS we can write something like this :

```
.container > div {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

But how to achieve the same code while using styled components library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target an immediate child div element of your Container component, you need to use `${Container} > & {}` to define those styles. Here's an example where I set separate styles for color, font-size, flex, and width based on whether or not the div is an immediate child of the Container component.

```
// Define the Container element styles
const Container = styled.div`
    font-size: 16px;
`;

// Define the ChildDiv element styles
const ChildDiv = styled.div`
    width: 50%;
    flex: 2;
    font-size: .5em;
    color: green;
    ${Container} > & {
        width: 100%;
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 2em;
        color: purple;
    }
`;

// Render components
render(
  <Container>
    <ChildDiv>
      This div is an immediate child of Container
      <ChildDiv>
        This div is NOT an immediate child of Container
      </ChildDiv>
    </ChildDiv>
  </Container>
);
```

Comment: yeah ...
I am checking on this. Could  I please ask you something on flex ? I think the example given by you will surely help in that ...

Comment: Actually I am using a flex box where I need to show all the items in on column one after another for desktop view and that is working fine.

But for Tablet view , I need to show two items in one row , then in next row -one item right side . again in next row - one item right side and finally in last row two items. Seems I am not being able to achieve two items in the same row having some space between them.

Comment: Please ask your question about what you want to achieve with display:flex for tablet views as a new Stack Overflow post so that people can help with that issue directly.  That will make it easier for people to find in the future if they have the same question.

Comment: yes I just did that.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413662/remove-unwanted-spaces-in-flexbox