# Remove unwanted spaces in flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have developed one flex box for desktop mode which is all right.
For tablet Mode how to achieve the below given design ?

https://codesandbox.io/embed/rjx6j8njqo

How to achieve two labels in the same row while using flex box?
Design is this :

[image]

So for tablet view : `min-width 640px` to `max-width 940px`,It should look like the picture attached.

May I please know how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope, below code will help you:

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 350px;
}

.item {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.item.gray {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.price {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: pink;
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 940px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .item {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .item:nth-child(3) {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <label>Label 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item gray">
    <label>Label 2</label>
    <span class="price">Price: $100</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item gray">
    <label>Label 3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <label>Change</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was making some mistakes in some flex-basis property..that solved the problem.
Your solution is also correct.Thanks.